# Conflict between python used by vim and by YouCompleteMe

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, vimscript-python

YCM does not work for the reason given above. When I type `:python import sys; print sys.version` I obtain:

```
2.7.9 (default, Dec 13 2014, 15:13:49)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)]
```

but when I compiled YCM, I set it up to use `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7`. Doing `./python2.7 --version` in this folder returns `2.7.10.`

I figured I could recompile vim and make it use the same python in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin`, but I don't see a way to do so. The option `--with-python-config-dir=PATH` doesn't seem to do much. In fact I can see in the `config.log`

```
configure:5872: checking for python
configure:5890: found /usr/bin/python
configure:5902: result: /usr/bin/python
configure:5915: checking Python version
configure:5924: result: 2.7
configure:5927: checking Python is 2.3 or better
configure:5932: result: yep
configure:5935: checking Python's install prefix
configure:5944: result: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
configure:5947: checking Python's execution prefix
configure:5956: result: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
configure:5978: checking Python's configuration directory
configure:6000: result: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config
configure:6059: checking Python's dll name
configure:6072: result: Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
configure:6088: checking if -pthread should be used
configure:6130: result: no
configure:6141: checking if compile and link flags for Python are sane
configure:6158: gcc -o conftest -g -O2 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -DPYTHON_HOME='"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7"'  -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -L/usr/local/lib conftest.c  -framework Python >&5
```

It looks like it will use also `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7`, but when I compile and type `:python import sys; print sys.version`  I still get 2.7.9. The python in `/usr/bin/python` is also 2.7.10 and it's not a symlink to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7`. This could be conflicting I guess. I also wanted to see where the python vim is using is by typing `python import sys; print sys.executable`, but this returns the vim bin, not python. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by using the command `lsof -p PID`. This gave me the python vim was using (which I couldn't find with `sys.executable`). Then I realized I was including this directory in `DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH` in my `.bash_profile`. I just deleted it and vim could pick up the correct python version.